# PDFKit navigate to page on click

Tags: html, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have used [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit) to generate pdf from html. But is there a way to navigate to nth page on click of an section(box element) on the page ?

Generate PDF:

```
content = PDFKit.new("#{header_html}<div class='pdf_image'><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,#{ Base64.encode64(chart1.read).gsub("\n", '')}'></img></div>
                                    <div class='pd_image' style='margin-top: 10%; page-break-after: always;'><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,#{ Base64.encode64(chart2.read).gsub("\n", '')}'></img></div>
                                    <div class='pdf_image' style='margin-top: 10%;'><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,#{ Base64.encode64(chart3.read).gsub("\n", '')}'></img></div>",
                                    orientation: 'landscape', margin_top: '0.2in', page_size: 'Letter')
send_data(content.to_pdf, filename: "all_charts.pdf", type: 'application/octetstream', disposition: 'inline')
```

Clicking on Box1 would do navigate to Page1 (current page).

Box 2 --> Page2

Box 3 --> Page3

Attached image explains what needs to happen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called as internal links.

Achieved with:

```
<a href='#box_1'></a>
<div name='box_1'></div>
```

Respectively for all boxes.

The only hurdle was with [wkhtmltopdf enable internal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506276/internal-links-with-wkhtmltopdf).